# Button displays toast and starts service

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two buttons (start/stop) that when clicked need to have a Toast pop up saying what has happened to the Service. Start = popup of "service has started" and the service actually starts. The service isn't finished and will be grabbing some GPS info later on.

Anyway, none of my Toasts show up and I'm hoping I'm not missing something obvious.

---

**Main (Activity)**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ParseService.class));
                }
        });

        Button stopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ParseService.class));
                }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**ParseService**

```
public class ParseService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent e, int flags, int startId){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service has Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service has Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:text="Stop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use the Application's Context from a Service and not the Service's Context.

From your Service:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  // application Context not 'this'
               "Service has Started",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Alternatively, you could display them from your Activity before you invoke the Service if you wish but I think where you have the calls currently positioned makes more sense and would reduce repetition later on as long as you always want the Toast displayed.

---

### **EDIT:**

Ok, after making a quick test app I think I found what might be going wrong for you.

Do you have the Service declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.indivisible.testapp">

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".toasts.ToastActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_toast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Define your Service as below.
             In my case the path is:
             .../TestApp/app/src/main/java/com/indivisible/testapp/toasts/ToastService.java
             Android Studio has a nice auto-complete when you press '.'
        -->
        <service
            android:name=".toasts.ToastService"
            android:label="ToastService">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Still no yummy Toast popping up. The reason I have them with the service is because since my service isn't doing anything right now I want to be sure that the service was run. Therefore if the Toast is run inside of the service I know that at least the onStartCommand in service was run.

Comment: @FrenchFruits, see my edit - I think I found your issue.

Comment: Have I ever told you I loved you? I'm new to android and more specifically dealing with xml. I forgot you basically have to declare everything you use in the manifest. Thank you so much! <3

Comment: Yeah, all the "entry points" like Activities, Receivers, Services etc.

Comment: Anyway, implement both of those suggestions above as even though the first didn't fix it it's still a problem it was just masked by the bigger issue the second part solves.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your service is not getting started, make sure the service is declared in the manifest and enabled as below:

```
 <service
        android:name=".ParseService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Hope this helps